Tortoise SVN Update and SVN Commit is missing after editing a file
I have an user with an issue with Tortoise, once he edits the file and try to run the SVN update or SVN commit, the options are missing. See the screenshots as reference.


We need to get the options available after the file is edited.

@Friedrich per the second screenshot, it seems to me that it shows a folder which is controlled by MS OneDrive. That's the main problem since AFAIK this can conflict with TortoiseSVN's integration. And it's a bad idea to store a working copy in such OneDrive/DropBox/iCloud Drive directory.

@bahrep well spotted! I'll remove my comment.

Move your working copy out of the OneDrive directory and this should resolve the issue. It's a bad idea to store SVN working copies (or any version-control repositories) in OneDrive/DropBox/iCloud Drive -controlled directories.
